# divs width (or height whichever one I can get to work) will not expand with content

Tags: html, css, jinja2

yes, I know this is a duplicate I haven't been able to fix it still. I've tried removing width but then the div is always the width of the entire page.
CSS for div:

```
.forum-post{
background-color: #F5DBA6;
margin-top: 20px;
border 3px solid #737D72;
min-width: 30%;
}
```

html for div:

```
<ul class="forum-replies">
    {% for reply in replies %}
    {% if reply.what_thread == 0 %}
    <li>
      <div class="forum-post">
          <h4 style="margin-top: 0px;"><text style="color: blue;">{{reply.title}}</text> - {{reply.name}} #{{reply.id}}- {{reply.date}} <a href="/b/{{reply.id}}">{Reply}</a></h4>
          {% if reply.filename %}
          <p style="margin-top: -20px;"><img src="{{url_for('static', filename = reply.filename )}}" height="100px" width="100px" align="left;" style="vertical-align: top;"/>
              {{reply.data|safe}}</p>
          {% else %}
          <p>{{reply.data|safe}}</p>
          {% endif %}

      </div>
    </li>
```

all css if it matters:

```
    <style>
    body {background-color: #82D57D ;}
    </style>
    <style>
    html, body, #fullheight {
    min-height: 100% !important;
    height: 100%;
}


      .home-container{
    background-color: rgb(190, 171, 239);
    height: auto;
    width: 1520px;
    border: 2px solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
    margin-left: 200px;
    margin-right: 200px;
    }

    .forum-post{
    background-color: #F5DBA6;
    margin-top: 20px;
    border 3px solid #737D72;
    margin-right: 600px;
    }


    .banner{
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    width: 50%;
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    }


    .link{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: grey;

    .t{
    color: blue;
    }

    }
```

I've tried several things for a couple of hours. I don't want to use overflow:auto since i dont want a scroll bar and want the div to actually get bigger. it used to do this fine before adding the image and some other things im not sure what happened. **if your confused about anything please lmk**
**EDIT**: sorry about the confusing title, I meant that I want the width to grow until the div hits the end of the div that it is inside. and then I want its height to grow. also all {{}} jinja variable are text except for the img
**EDIT#2**: the div is inside the home container div btw, and that div is not inside anything

Comment: could you please explain you want your div width to grow or div height?

Comment: try `width: fit-content` for parent div.

Comment: @fmsthird this works! ty! but now i want the div to get taller when it reaches the end of the screen, which it does not.

Comment: @june did you try the same for height, `height: fit-content` ?

Comment: @fmsthird yes. the div just keeps going to the right

Comment: well that is expected, you need to set `max-width` so that text or content will wrap and height will expand

Comment: @fmsthird i did set max width to 90%. the div just stops at 90% width and the text keeps going to the right and does not wrap around.

Comment: @june you can apply in combination with max-width the `word-wrap: break-word;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply `max-width: fit-content;` to the parent div plus `word-break: break-word;` to wrap the text after hitting the max width limit.